# MediaElement animation activation loop doesn't trigger last 3 animations

Tags: c#, wpf

During my loop, my screen does not populate the last 3 `MediaElement`s. If I expand or shrink the `MediaElement` array....

```
MediaElement[] mygif = new MediaElement[30];
```

from 30 elements to 40 elements, it will display 37 elements.

Here is the full source code for this method, if you notice the first media element is hidden, this is on purpose.

```
private void LoadGifScreen()
{
    Window GifBrowserCmd = new Window();
    GifBrowserCmd.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    GifBrowserCmd.Width = 200;
    GifBrowserCmd.Height = screenHeight * .8;
    GifBrowserCmd.Left = screenWidth - GifBrowserCmd.Width;
    GifBrowserCmd.Top = screenHeight*.1;
    GifBrowserCmd.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
    GifBrowserCmd.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
    GifBrowserCmd.Background = BaseColor;
    GifBrowserCmd.AllowsTransparency = true;
    GifBrowserCmd.Opacity = toolOpacity;

    MediaElement[] mygif = new MediaElement[30];
    gborder = new Border[30];
    GifCanvas = new Canvas();
    int brdr_height = 150;
    GifCanvas.Height = brdr_height * mygif.Count();
    GifList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    DoubleAnimation[] anim2 = new DoubleAnimation[30];
    bool[] animsact = new bool[30];
    for (int i = 0; i < mygif.Count(); i++)
    {
        mygif[i] = new MediaElement();
        gborder[i] = new Border();
        mygif[i].UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
        mygif[i].LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        mygif[i].Source = new Uri(@filesArray[i]);
        GifList.Add(i, filesArray[i]);
        mygif[i].Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
        mygif[i].Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
        mygif[i].Play();

        mygif[i].MediaEnded += (o, r) =>
        {
            MediaElement tmp = (MediaElement)o;
            int tmpkey = 0;
            string searchstring = tmp.Source.AbsolutePath.ToString().Replace("%20", " ").Replace("/", @"\").Replace("\\", @"\");
            if (GifList.ContainsValue(searchstring))
            {
                tmpkey = GifList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == searchstring).Key;
            }
            mygif[tmpkey].Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            mygif[tmpkey].Play();
        };
        mygif[i].PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (o, m) =>
        {
            MediaElement tmp = (MediaElement)o;
            int tmpkey = 0;
            string searchstring = tmp.Source.AbsolutePath.ToString().Replace("%20", " ").Replace("/", @"\").Replace("\\", @"\");
            if (GifList.ContainsValue(searchstring))
            {
                tmpkey = GifList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == searchstring).Key;
                LoadGifDetailScreen(tmpkey);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Couldn't find gif in Dictionary!");
            }
        };

        gborder[i].BorderBrush = Brushes.White;
        gborder[i].BorderThickness = new Thickness(3, 3, 3, 3);
        gborder[i].CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(8, 8, 8, 8);
        gborder[i].Child = mygif[i];
        gborder[i].Width = 200;
        gborder[i].Height = brdr_height;
        GifCanvas.Children.Add(gborder[i]);
        Canvas.SetTop(gborder[i], (i * gborder[i].Height) + (bigspacer * i) - gborder[i].Height);
        Canvas.SetLeft(gborder[i], gborder[i].Width);
        gborder[i].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

        mygif[i].MediaOpened += (l,p) => {
            MediaElement tmp = (MediaElement)l;
            int tmpkey = 0;
            string searchstring = tmp.Source.AbsolutePath.ToString().Replace("%20", " ").Replace("/", @"\").Replace("\\", @"\");
            if (GifList.ContainsValue(searchstring))
            {
                tmpkey = GifList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == searchstring).Key;
                tmpkey--;
            }
            TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
            gborder[tmpkey].RenderTransform = trans;
            anim2[tmpkey] = new DoubleAnimation(gborder[tmpkey].Width, 0 - gborder[tmpkey].Width, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.25));
            anim2[tmpkey].Completed += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (position <= mygif.Count()) {
                    gborder[position].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim2[position]);
                    position++;
                }
            };
            if (tmpkey == 0)
            {
                gborder[(tmpkey)].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim2[(tmpkey)]);
                position++;
            }
        };
    }
    ScrollViewer sv1 = new ScrollViewer();
    sv1.CanContentScroll = true;
    sv1.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
    sv1.Height = GifBrowserCmd.Height;
    sv1.Content = GifCanvas;
    GifBrowserGrid.Children.Add(sv1);
    GifBrowserCmd.Content = GifBrowserGrid;
    GifBrowserCmd.Show();
    GifBrowserCmd.Deactivated += GifListCmd_Deactivated;
}
```

How can I activate the entire `MediaElement` array's animations?

**UPDATE**

Adding code from Netscapes answer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int spacer = 2;
        int bigspacer;
        double toolOpacity = 1;
        double windowWidth = 50;
        double windowHeight = 50;
        double totalwidth;
        double centerApp;
        double screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
        double screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;

        List<MediaElement> mygif;
        List<Border> gborder;
        List<DoubleAnimation> anim2;
        List<bool> animsact;
        Dictionary<int, string> GifList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        int _pos = 0;
        Canvas GifCanvas;
        Grid GifBrowserGrid = new Grid();
        private int position
        {
            get
            {
                return _pos;
            }
            set
            {
                _pos = value;
                //Console.WriteLine(_pos);
            }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Window GifBrowserCmd = new Window();
            GifBrowserCmd.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            GifBrowserCmd.Width = 200;
            GifBrowserCmd.Height = screenHeight * .8;
            GifBrowserCmd.Left = screenWidth - GifBrowserCmd.Width;
            GifBrowserCmd.Top = screenHeight * .1;
            GifBrowserCmd.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
            GifBrowserCmd.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
            GifBrowserCmd.Background = Brushes.Black;
            GifBrowserCmd.AllowsTransparency = true;
            GifBrowserCmd.Opacity = toolOpacity;
            GifCanvas = new Canvas();
            GifList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            string[] filesArray = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\Images\\Animated Images\\");

            mygif = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(d => new MediaElement()).ToList();
            gborder = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(d => new Border()).ToList();
            anim2 = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(d => new DoubleAnimation()).ToList();
            animsact = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(d => false).ToList();
            GifCanvas = new Canvas();
            int brdr_height = 150;
            GifCanvas.Height = brdr_height * mygif.Count();

            for (int i = 0; i < mygif.Count(); i++)
            {
                GifList.Add(i, filesArray[i]);
                mygif[i] = new MediaElement();
                mygif[i].Source = new Uri(@filesArray[i]);
                gborder[i] = new Border();

                //Setup MediaElement
                mygif[i].UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
                mygif[i].LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
                mygif[i].MediaEnded += MediaEndedHandler;
                mygif[i].PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownHandler;
                mygif[i].MediaOpened += MediaOpened;

                mygif[i].Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
                mygif[i].Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
                mygif[i].Play();

                //Setup Border
                gborder[i].BorderBrush = Brushes.White;
                gborder[i].BorderThickness = new Thickness(3, 3, 3, 3);
                gborder[i].CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(8, 8, 8, 8);
                gborder[i].Child = mygif[i];
                gborder[i].Width = 200;
                gborder[i].Height = brdr_height;

                GifCanvas.Children.Add(gborder[i]);
                Canvas.SetTop(gborder[i], (i * gborder[i].Height) + (bigspacer * i));// - gborder[i].Height);
                Canvas.SetLeft(gborder[i], gborder[i].Width);
                //Comment the below line out to see if shows them all has an effect
                //gborder[i].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            }

            ScrollViewer sv1 = new ScrollViewer();
            sv1.CanContentScroll = true;
            sv1.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
            sv1.Height = GifBrowserCmd.Height;
            sv1.Content = GifCanvas;
            GifBrowserGrid.Children.Add(sv1);
            GifBrowserCmd.Content = GifBrowserGrid;
            GifBrowserCmd.Show();
            //GifBrowserCmd.Deactivated += GifListCmd_Deactivated;
        }

        private void MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaElement tmp = (MediaElement)sender;
            int tmpkey = 0;
            string searchstring = tmp.Source.AbsolutePath.ToString().Replace("%20", " ").Replace("/", @"\").Replace("\\", @"\");
            if (GifList.ContainsValue(searchstring))
            {
                tmpkey = GifList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == searchstring).Key;
                tmpkey--;
            }
            TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
            gborder[tmpkey].RenderTransform = trans;
            anim2[tmpkey] = new DoubleAnimation(gborder[tmpkey].Width, 0 - gborder[tmpkey].Width, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.25));
            anim2[tmpkey].Completed += AnimationCompleted;
            if (tmpkey == 0)
            {
                gborder[(tmpkey)].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim2[(tmpkey)]);
                position++;
            }
        }

        private void AnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (position < mygif.Count())
            {
                try
                {
                bool changed = false;
                if (position == 19)
                {
                    changed = true;
                }
                    gborder[position].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    gborder[position].RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
                    gborder[position].RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim2[position++]);

                }
                catch (Exception f)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(f.InnerException.Data.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        private void PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaElement tmp = (MediaElement)sender;
            int tmpkey = 0;
            string searchstring = tmp.Source.AbsolutePath.ToString().Replace("%20", " ").Replace("/", @"\").Replace("\\", @"\");
            if (GifList.ContainsValue(searchstring))
            {
                tmpkey = GifList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == searchstring).Key;
                //LoadGifDetailScreen(tmpkey);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Couldn't find gif in Dictionary!");
            }
        }

        private void MediaEndedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaElement tmp = (MediaElement)sender;
            int tmpkey = 0;
            string searchstring = tmp.Source.AbsolutePath.ToString().Replace("%20", " ").Replace("/", @"\").Replace("\\", @"\");
            if (GifList.ContainsValue(searchstring))
            {
                tmpkey = GifList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == searchstring).Key;
            }
            mygif[tmpkey].Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            mygif[tmpkey].Play();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like 3 of your animations don't load. I'd make sure they are there using step through debugging. Then I'd check your screen is wide enough to fit all of them

Comment: Tried that first. My animation array was 20 elements, and only showed 17. Set it at 30 to see if 13 would not show. Nope, only the last 3. The screen is a vertical auto sizing canvas in a scroll viewer, so it has the space for the media elements, but the last three don't perform the doubleanimation. Thank you for your input though.

Comment: I think it has to do with my auto activation under the nested MediaOpened action which increments the position variable. But when I set a debug, it incremented appropriately through the last three elements.

Comment: What is `GifBrowserCmd` ?

Comment: Also, you should use `mygif.Length` instead of `.Count()`

Comment: `GifBrowserCmd` is a dynamic window, it's created at the top.

Comment: Is it really _the shortest code necessary to reproduce_ your problem ?

Comment: @franssu Well the MediaElement's DoubleAnimation's XProperty is relative to the dynamic screens position, size and content, so yeah it is.

Comment: What about `MessageBox.Show("Couldn't find gif in Dictionary!");` ?

Comment: You mean, the `if else` statement that show's how the dictionary allocates the gif key? Yup. Still relative.

Comment: Removing it makes the bug disappear ? It's really unlikely, so your sample is not minimal.

Comment: Also, we don't have `screenHeight`, `screenWidth`, `BaseColor`, `toolOpacity`, `gborder`, `GifCanvas`, `filesArray`, `GifList`, `LoadGifDetailScreen`, ... so it's likely that you're sample is neither _complete_, so your question should be deleted unless you do massive refactoring of your sample.

Comment: So, first it was, "do you need that much code" now it's "you need more code". If you know c#/wpf the variables are relatively clear. I think the only thing that needs to be deleted are your comments. Try to understand the code before you comment on it.

Comment: Your question should be closed, it's off-topic because it doesn't provide the **shortest necessary** code to reproduce the bug. There's a flagging category for these kind of questions. I was first complaining that there was **too much code** for it to be the **shortest**, then that, furthermore,  there's not even **enough code** for it to be **necessary**.  So, really, you've double failed to be on topic, and that maybe why you didn't attract many attention / answers. Please see : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks. Next time, avoid all the rhetoric and post that link first. Not many people will receive your complaining positively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suspect that it might be something with `position` being incremented and the way you're generating `tmpkey`.  I would also recommend not using lambdas for your event handlers, it might be a safer route to use local methods instead.

After your control is displayed, use Snoop to inspect your control and determine if all 30 controls are actually being added to the UI.  If they are, then something is wrong with your code in the matter that the controls are overlapping you're just not setting the visibility correctly (so that's why I commented out the one line below, for debugging).

Here is a line that makes me raise an eyebrow:

```
tmpkey = GifList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == searchstring).Key;
tmpkey--;
```

If this runs on your first element, dictionary key = 0, then `tmpkey--` would be `-1`.  If it runs on your last element, `tmpkey` would be `28` and never equal `29`, so your arrays being accessed with `tmpkey` as the index wouldn't get the properties assigned.  Related--is something happening in `LoadGifDetailScreen`?

I created a property with a setter that sets `position` and prints out the value every time it is set.  Watch your output window to see if you notice any interesting increments. I have also modified the code so it reads a little cleaner (I will be editing the question to remove the optimization tag).

**Code:**

```
List<MediaElement> mygif;
List<Border> gborder;
List<DoubleAnimation> anim2;
List<bool> animsact;
Dictionary<int, string> GifList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
int _pos = 0;
private int position
{
    get
    {
        return _pos;
    }
    set
    {
        _pos = value;
        Console.WriteLine(_pos);
    }
}
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    mygif = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(d => new MediaElement()).ToList();
    gborder = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(d => new Border()).ToList();
    anim2 = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(d => new DoubleAnimation()).ToList();
    animsact = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(d => false).ToList();
    GifCanvas = new Canvas();
    int brdr_height = 150;
    GifCanvas.Height = brdr_height * mygif.Count;

    for(int i = 0; i < mygif.Count; i++)
    {
        //Setup MediaElement
        mygif[i].UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
        mygif[i].LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        mygif[i].MediaEnded += MediaEndedHandler;
        mygif[i].PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownHandler;
        mygif[i].MediaOpened += MainWindow_MediaOpened;

        //Setup Border
        gborder[i].BorderBrush = Brushes.White;
        gborder[i].BorderThickness = new Thickness(3, 3, 3, 3);
        gborder[i].CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(8, 8, 8, 8);
        gborder[i].Child = mygif[i];
        gborder[i].Width = 200;
        gborder[i].Height = brdr_height;

        GifCanvas.Children.Add(gborder[i]);
        Canvas.SetTop(gborder[i], (i * gborder[i].Height) + (bigspacer * i) - gborder[i].Height);
        Canvas.SetLeft(gborder[i], gborder[i].Width);
        //Comment the below line out to see if shows them all has an effect
        //gborder[i].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    ScrollViewer sv1 = new ScrollViewer();
    sv1.CanContentScroll = true;
    sv1.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
    sv1.Height = GifBrowserCmd.Height;
    sv1.Content = GifCanvas;
    GifBrowserGrid.Children.Add(sv1);
    GifBrowserCmd.Content = GifBrowserGrid;
    GifBrowserCmd.Show();
    GifBrowserCmd.Deactivated += GifListCmd_Deactivated;
}

private void MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MediaElement tmp = (MediaElement)sender;
    int tmpkey = 0;
    string searchstring = tmp.Source.AbsolutePath.ToString().Replace("%20", " ").Replace("/", @"\").Replace("\\", @"\");
    if(GifList.ContainsValue(searchstring))
    {
        tmpkey = GifList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == searchstring).Key;
        tmpkey--;
    }
    TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
    gborder[tmpkey].RenderTransform = trans;
    anim2[tmpkey] = new DoubleAnimation(gborder[tmpkey].Width, 0 - gborder[tmpkey].Width, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.25));
    anim2[tmpkey].Completed += AnimationCompleted;
    if(tmpkey == 0)
    {
        gborder[(tmpkey)].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim2[(tmpkey)]);
        position++;
    }
}

private void AnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(position < mygif.Count)
    {
        gborder[position].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        gborder[position].RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim2[position++]);
    }
}

private void PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MediaElement tmp = (MediaElement)sender;
    int tmpkey = 0;
    string searchstring = tmp.Source.AbsolutePath.ToString().Replace("%20", " ").Replace("/", @"\").Replace("\\", @"\");
    if(GifList.ContainsValue(searchstring))
    {
        tmpkey = GifList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == searchstring).Key;
        LoadGifDetailScreen(tmpkey);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Couldn't find gif in Dictionary!");
    }
}

private void MediaEndedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MediaElement tmp = (MediaElement)sender;
    int tmpkey = 0;
    string searchstring = tmp.Source.AbsolutePath.ToString().Replace("%20", " ").Replace("/", @"\").Replace("\\", @"\");
    if(GifList.ContainsValue(searchstring))
    {
        tmpkey = GifList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == searchstring).Key;
    }
    mygif[tmpkey].Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    mygif[tmpkey].Play();
}
```

Comment: If this doesn't solve it, then post what it is `GifListCmd_Deactivated` because we have to realize that that event is hooked up immediately since `Window.Show()` does not block.

Comment: Nothing applicable is happening on LoadGifDetailScreen and the Deactivated method just puts the window always on top so don't worry about that. This is good stuff! Let me try this code out a little later and I'll let you know.

Comment: Also, any reason you use Enumeration rather than dictionaries or lists? Just curious.

Comment: You're code works well, except it doesn't show the last element. No errors thrown though.

Comment: I've added the entire source code to the question to show the result.

Comment: @Rich use `mygif.Count` without the `()`.  Also not sure if you really want to do `tmpkey--;`.  The code is adding all the elements to the canvas, you're doing something that is preventing it from being shown like preventing properties/etc. from being applied to the last element or not making the control "tall" enough. FYI `(bigspacer * i)` will always = 0.

Comment: Also make sure you have file names `0` through `19` in the folder and not `1` through `20`... not sure what `@filesArray[i]` is doing either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98735/discussion-between-rich-and-netscape).

Comment: Thanks NETscape. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the completed answer from NETscape's help. I had to rearrange some of the code so it functioned appropriately.

```
    int spacer = 2;
    int bigspacer;
    double toolOpacity = 1;
    double windowWidth = 50;
    double windowHeight = 50;
    double totalwidth;
    double centerApp;
    double screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
    double screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;

    List<MediaElement> mygif;
    List<Border> gborder;
    List<DoubleAnimation> anim2;
    List<bool> animsact;
    Dictionary<int, string> GifList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    int _pos = 0;
    Canvas GifCanvas;
    Grid GifBrowserGrid = new Grid();
    private int position
    {
        get
        {
            return _pos;
        }
        set
        {
            _pos = value;
            //Console.WriteLine(_pos);
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Window GifBrowserCmd = new Window();
        GifBrowserCmd.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        GifBrowserCmd.Width = 200;
        GifBrowserCmd.Height = screenHeight * .8;
        GifBrowserCmd.Left = screenWidth - GifBrowserCmd.Width;
        GifBrowserCmd.Top = screenHeight * .1;
        GifBrowserCmd.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
        GifBrowserCmd.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
        GifBrowserCmd.Background = Brushes.Black;
        GifBrowserCmd.AllowsTransparency = true;
        GifBrowserCmd.Opacity = toolOpacity;
        GifCanvas = new Canvas();
        GifList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        string[] filesArray = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\Images\\Animated Images\\");

        mygif = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(d => new MediaElement()).ToList();
        gborder = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(d => new Border()).ToList();
        anim2 = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(d => new DoubleAnimation()).ToList();
        animsact = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(d => false).ToList();
        GifCanvas = new Canvas();
        int brdr_height = 150;
        GifCanvas.Height = brdr_height * mygif.Count();

        for (int i = 0; i < mygif.Count(); i++)
        {
            GifList.Add(i, filesArray[i]);
            mygif[i] = new MediaElement();
            mygif[i].Source = new Uri(@filesArray[i]);
            gborder[i] = new Border();

            //Setup MediaElement
            mygif[i].UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
            mygif[i].LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
            mygif[i].MediaEnded += MediaEndedHandler;
            mygif[i].PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownHandler;
            mygif[i].MediaOpened += MediaOpened;

            mygif[i].Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
            mygif[i].Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
            mygif[i].Play();

            //Setup Border
            gborder[i].BorderBrush = Brushes.White;
            gborder[i].BorderThickness = new Thickness(3, 3, 3, 3);
            gborder[i].CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(8, 8, 8, 8);
            gborder[i].Child = mygif[i];
            gborder[i].Width = 200;
            gborder[i].Height = brdr_height;

            GifCanvas.Children.Add(gborder[i]);
            Canvas.SetTop(gborder[i], (i * gborder[i].Height) + (bigspacer * i));// - gborder[i].Height);
            Canvas.SetLeft(gborder[i], gborder[i].Width);
            //Comment the below line out to see if shows them all has an effect
            //gborder[i].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        ScrollViewer sv1 = new ScrollViewer();
        sv1.CanContentScroll = true;
        sv1.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
        sv1.Height = GifBrowserCmd.Height;
        sv1.Content = GifCanvas;
        GifBrowserGrid.Children.Add(sv1);
        GifBrowserCmd.Content = GifBrowserGrid;
        GifBrowserCmd.Show();
        //GifBrowserCmd.Deactivated += GifListCmd_Deactivated;
    }

    private void MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement tmp = (MediaElement)sender;
        int tmpkey = 0;
        string searchstring = tmp.Source.AbsolutePath.ToString().Replace("%20", " ").Replace("/", @"\").Replace("\\", @"\");
        if (GifList.ContainsValue(searchstring))
        {
            tmpkey = GifList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == searchstring).Key;
            //tmpkey--;
        }
        TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
        gborder[tmpkey].RenderTransform = trans;
        anim2[tmpkey] = new DoubleAnimation(gborder[tmpkey].Width, 0 - gborder[tmpkey].Width, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.25));
        anim2[tmpkey].Completed += AnimationCompleted;
        if (tmpkey == 0)
        {
            gborder[(tmpkey)].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim2[(tmpkey)]);
            position++;
        }
    }

    private void AnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (position < mygif.Count())
        {
            try
            {
            bool changed = false;
            if (position == 19)
            {
                changed = true;
            }
                gborder[position].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                gborder[position].RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
                gborder[position].RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim2[position++]);

            }
            catch (Exception f)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(f.InnerException.Data.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement tmp = (MediaElement)sender;
        int tmpkey = 0;
        string searchstring = tmp.Source.AbsolutePath.ToString().Replace("%20", " ").Replace("/", @"\").Replace("\\", @"\");
        if (GifList.ContainsValue(searchstring))
        {
            tmpkey = GifList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == searchstring).Key;
            //LoadGifDetailScreen(tmpkey);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't find gif in Dictionary!");
        }
    }

    private void MediaEndedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement tmp = (MediaElement)sender;
        int tmpkey = 0;
        string searchstring = tmp.Source.AbsolutePath.ToString().Replace("%20", " ").Replace("/", @"\").Replace("\\", @"\");
        if (GifList.ContainsValue(searchstring))
        {
            tmpkey = GifList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == searchstring).Key;
        }
        mygif[tmpkey].Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        mygif[tmpkey].Play();
    }
```